# Primary Key and GSI Design in DynamoDB

Tags: primary-key, amazon-dynamodb, secondary-indexes

I've recently started learning DynamoDB and created a table 'reviews' with the following attributes (along with the DynamoDB type):

```
productId - String
username - String
feedbackText - String
lastModifiedDate - Number (I'm storing the UNIX timestamp)
createdDate - Number
active - Number (0/1 value, 1 for all records by default)
```

Following are the queries that I expect to run on this table:

```
1. Get all reviews for a 'productId'
2. Get all reviews submitted by a 'username' (sorted asc/desc by lastModifiedDate)
3. Get N most recent reviews across products and users (using lastModifiedDate)
```

Now in order to be able to run these queries I have created the following on the 'reviews' table:

```
1. A Primary Key with 'productId' as the Hash Key and 'username' as the Range Key
2. A GSI with 'username' as the Hash Key and 'lastModifiedDate' as the Range Key
3. A GSI with 'active' as the Hash Key and 'lastModifiedDate' as the Range Key
```

The last index is somewhat of a hack since I introduced the 'active' attribute in my table only so that the value can be '1' for all records and I can use it as a Hash Key for the GSI.

My question is simple. I've read a bit about DynamoDB already and this is the best design I could come up with. I want to ask if there is a better primary key/index design that I could be using here. If there is a concept in DynamoDB which I may have missed that could be beneficial in this specific use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your design is correct:

- the table key and GSI from point 2 will cover your first two queries. No surprises here, this is pretty standard.
- I think your design for the last query is correct, even if somewhat hacky and possibly not the best in terms of performance. Using the same value for hash key is what you need to do considering DynamoDB limitations. You want to be able to get values in order so you need to use a range key. As you want to only use the range key, you need to provide the same value for the hash key. You should just note that this *may* not scale very well when your table grows into many partitions (though I don't have any data to back that statement up).